# How to show/hide labels customizely in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I have drawn a graph using highcharts.js library. I want the `xAxis` a little bit customized. I want to show labels in `xAxis` but I want to show and hide alternate lables. I mean I want to show labels like 1,3,5 etc. Number 2.4.6 will be drawn but just the label won't be shown for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can also set [tickInterval](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickInterval) as 2.

Answer (score 0):

You have an option called ***step*** in the x-axis label property, To show only every *n* <sup>*th*</sup> label on the axis, set the step to n.

In your case, Setting the step to 2 (just like below) shows every other label.

```
xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr'],
            labels: {
                step: 2
            }
        }
```

Find an example [`here`](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/xaxis/labels-step/) and help yourself with the API [`here`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.labels.step).